# Down-sampling MNIST dataset for CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

For my Deep Learning Course, I need to implement a neural network which is exactly the same as the Tensorflow MNIST for Experts Tutorial. ,

The only difference is that I need to down-sampşe the database, then put it into the neural network. Should I crop and resize, or should I implement the neural network with parameters which accepts multiple data sizes(28x28 and 14x14).

All of the parameters in the tensorflow tutorial is static so I couldn't find a way to feed the algorithm with a 14x14 image. Which tool should I use for 'optimal' down-sampling?

Answer (score 0):

You need resize the input images to a fixed size (which appears tp be 14*14 from your description). There are different ways for doing this, for example, you can use interpolation to resize, simply crop the central part or some corner of the image, or randomly chose one or many patches (all of the same size as your network's input) from a give image. You can also combine these methods. For example, in VGG, they first do a aspect preserving resize using bilinear interpolation and then get a random patch from the resulting image (for test phase they get the central crop). You can find VGG's preprocessing source code in TensorFlow at the following link:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/preprocessing/vgg_preprocessing.py

The only parameters of sample code in the tutorial you have mentioned that needs to be changed are those related to the input image sizes. For example, you need to change 28s to 14s and 784s to 228s (these are just examples, there are other wight sizes that you will need to change as well).

Comment: When I change all the 28's to 14 and change all the 784's to 196, I get the following error:
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 1024 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 3136
  [[Node: Reshape_1 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](MaxPool_1, Reshape_1/shape)]]

In oder to try this , I sampled the dataset using numpy.resize, although I know it is not the correct way to do it

Comment: At least you can add the line of code which is causing this error.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I added it but I did not. Here it is: 

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

Comment: 28s and 784s aren't the only things that need to modified, I mentioned them just as examples. The problem is that when you change the input, the output of the convolutional layers will change so you  need to have a look at the weights which need to be updated accordingly.